# prove that the series $\sum\frac{1}{f(k)}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

I just proved $\sum\frac{x^n}{(2n)!}$ is convergent for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Define the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(2n)!}$$
Now the question says; **prove that the series $\sum\frac{1}{f(k)}$ is convergent.**

Now I'm having difficulty understanding this question, do we sum up like $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(k)}$ hence having to kinda deal with $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ or is it something different? (I'm suspecting that to be honest, I mean what else could it really be).

Then after clarification, hints are preferred as this is test preparation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x\geq 1$, $$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2{}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$
So $$\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}+e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(2n)!}.$$
So $$f(k)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{k}}+e^{-\sqrt{k}}}{2},k\geq 1,$$
and the series $$\sum \frac{1}{f(k)}$$ is convergent.

Comment: Oh woah is that because exp $x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ right? Yeah our lecturer snuck that in, thought it was just this cool side fact.

Comment: But then wouldn't that mean that $2e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}?$

Comment: No it wouldn't, disregard sorry.

Comment: But yeah, thanks!

Comment: I would probably confine myself to using $\frac{e^x}{2} = \sum\frac{x^n}{(2n)!}$. It seems simpler.

Comment: @FlorianSuess $\frac{e^x}{2} \neq \sum\frac{x^n}{(2n)!}$, since $2\cdot n!=2\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot n \neq 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot 2n=(2n)!$

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this without explicitly knowing what $f(k)$ is. Clearly you have for $k>0$ that $f(k)\ge \frac{k^2}{4!}$ so $\frac1{f(k)}\le \frac{24}{k^2}$. Now you can use the comparison test and the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}$ converges.

Comment: You method is very nice!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} x^n/(2n)! = \cosh{(\sqrt{x})}$ and $\frac{1}{\cosh{\sqrt{x}}} = \operatorname{sech} {\sqrt{x}}$ then use comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you sum up as $\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)$. Explicitly, this is a double sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Biggl(\frac 1{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k^n}{(2n)!}}\Biggr).$$